# Video.js Seek Bar - Seek point behind mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I'm using Video.js (v6.9) and I don't understand why the seek position is behind the mouse cursor. The worst part is, Firefox is the only browser that renders it correctly, so I can't pinpoint what the issue is. Here's a screen grab of what's happening:

[image]

Now this is the desired result - from YouTube:

[image]

Basically, where the mouse is clicked is not where the video starts.

Things I've tried:

- Updating Video.js from 6.2 to 6.9
- Removing all custom styles

Any idea what's happening here? I'm using React and NPM if that's helpful.

Comment: This needs a [mcve] to be able to tell what's wrong

Comment: May you provide a fiddle with that bug?This way it's easy to fork and try to fix it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify your own class to your videojs component to override the default videojs styling or :

```
.video-js .vjs-progress-control .vjs-mouse-display {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rmwokj6rrq

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not just a visual thing. Whenever the seek position is clicked, the video jumps to the point that's behind the mouse. So hiding the position display won't fix the issue.

Comment: I think video goes to the seek position on click is the expected behavior. Can you post the expected result gif?

Comment: Gotcha, it is the position of seek opaque bar that you are looking to fix. It's white on youtube and grey in your case. Thanks for the update!